# why ionic checkboxes looks different on android?

Tags: ionic-framework

Any idea why ionic checkbox round shapes are gone after build into app. Round shape becomes square, and functions are OK. It looks fine on browser but android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes are platform specific. Checkboxes are round for iOS and square for android. 
check this link out for more clarification:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/beta-14-checkboxes-are-square/14346

Hope I helped.